# Convert Xamarin.Forms StackLayout to Android View

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I am trying to convert Xamarin.Forms stack layout to Android native View class to use it in IWindowManager.AddView method.

Conversion code is

```
static class ViewToAndroidViewConverter
{
    public static Android.Views.View GetNativeView(this VisualElement view)
    {
        if (Platform.GetRenderer(view) == null)
            Platform.SetRenderer(view, Platform.CreateRenderer(view));
        var renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(view);
        renderer.Tracker.UpdateLayout();

        return renderer.ViewGroup;
    }
}
```

And this is StackLayout that I am trying to convert

```
StackLayout testView = new StackLayout();
testView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Incoming call text" });
testView.Children.Add(new Label { Text = incomingNumber });
testView.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;

windowManager.AddView( testView.GetNativeView(),
            new WindowManagerLayoutParams {
                Title = "Call title sample",
                Gravity = GravityFlags.Center,
                Type = WindowManagerTypes.SystemAlert,
                Height = 500,
                Width = 1080
            });
```

The problem is that this test view is shown, but without label contents (solid green rectangle only).
Is there any way to create an android native view from stack layout with full contents?